# How to find the zeroes of the derivative of this function?

Tags: calculus

I need to determine the integral of the function $ f(x)=4x\times sin(3-x^2) $ that has the property that it's greatest value is $9$. The integral of $ f(x)=4x\times sin(3-x^2) $ is $ F(x)=2cos(3-x^2)+C $, but I'm stuck on finding the zeroes of the derivative so that I could find the correct value for $C$.

From $4x\times sin(3-x^2)=0$ I can get that one of the zeroes is $x=0$, but I'm not sure about the other zeroes. My calculator gives them as $x=\pm\sqrt{n\pi+3}$, but when I try to calculate them myself I get $x=\sqrt{-n2\pi-\pi+3}$ and $x=\sqrt{3-n2\pi}$. I have basically no idea how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin(3-x^2)=0\iff 3-x^2=n\pi\ (n\in\mathbb{Z},\ n\le 0)\iff x^2=3-n\pi\iff x=\pm\sqrt{3-n\pi}$$
if you want $n$ to be $\ge 0$ then take $-n$ instead of $n$.

Comment: Thanks! How would I go about solving the rest of the problem? I'm stuck since the function is trigonometric but it doesn't have a constant periodicity.

Comment: You want $2\cos(3-x^2)+C$ to be $\le 9$ with equality in some points. Take $C=7$.

Comment: To add to ton_nor's point, the reason we want to take C = 7 is because $\forall x \cos(x) \leq 1$ and so $2 \cos(3 - x^2) \leq 2$ therefore $2 \cos(3 - x^2) \leq 2$ + 7 $\leq$ 9.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\cos(x)\leq 1,\ \forall x$.